# How to refer to an equation in a different page with Mathjax

Tags: mathjax

I have several html pages with a lot of equations rendered by Mathjax. I would like to refer to several equations not especially in the same page.

The problem is that "\eqref" is only working if the equation is in the same page.

One solution would be to use "\tag{}" for all equations and use simple html links.

For example,

```
\label{myequation} \tag{4.1}
```

and the link would be

```
"<a href="http://www.mysite.com/mypage#myequation"> 4.1 </a>"
```

The problem with that solution is that I need to have personal tag for all equations.

Does anyone has a solution for referring to equations in different pages by producing tags automatically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation for [automatic equation numbering](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#automatic-equation-numbering).  This allows you to have your equations numbered automatically rather than requiring `\tag`.  Note that any numbered or tagged equation automatically gets an ID that can be used in a link, so there is no requirement to use `\label` (though it helps if you are adding and removing equations during editing).  If an equation is numbered 5, then the id is `mjx-eqn-5`.  There are functions that you can override in order to change the format of the equation numbers.  See the `equationNumbers` section of the [TeX configuration parameters](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/TeX.html#configure-tex) documentation.

**Edit**: Now that I understand your request, I can tell you that to do what you ask for would require MathJax to know the label-to-tag mapping for the other pages in your site (not just the page currently being viewed).  MathJax doesn't have that data available to it. The only way to do it would be to create data files for the other pages that includes that data so that MathJax could load it  and have it available.  While technically possible, it would be a bit cumbersome to do that, especially since JavaScript (normally) can't write files for you.

On the other hand, the only place the label-to-tag mapping is needed is for the text that acts as the link itself (that is, if `eq:sum` refers to equation 4.1, then you would want "4.1" to be the text that links to that equation.  Note that the link itself will be to `myotherpage#eq:sum`, so the only thing that needs the number is the link text itself.  If you were willing to use something like "[sum]" as the link text for `eq:sum` (e.g., "In equation [sum] we see..."), then you would not need the label-to-tag mapping, and `\eqref` could be modified to handle that.  But if you really want the equation number as the link, you would need a *lot* more infrastructure to make that happen.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but with your solution I still need to produce labels for the link (e.g "4.1"). Maybe I didn't understand but how do you make a link to an equation without adding "label" in <a> label </a> ?

Comment: If an equation is tagged (either automatically or by an explicit `\tag`), then it automatically gets an ID that you can use as the target of a link.  So if you have `$$E=mc^2\tag(4.1)$$`, then the equation will have an id of `mjx-eqn-4.1`, and you can use `<a href="http://www.mysite.com/mypage#mjx-eqn-4.1">4.1</a>` in other files to link to that equation.  You do not need an explicit `\label{}` in the TeX code (though you certainly can use one if you wish, so that if you add or remove equations, you don't have to change the link has reference).  Perhaps I don't understand what you are after.

Comment: If this is not what you are after, can you edit your question to make it more explicit what you what to do?  Perhaps an example of what you would like to do?

Comment: Thanks. Actually, what I want to avoid is to give a label for all my links `<a href="http://www.mysite.com/mypage#mjx-eqn-4.1">4.1</a>`. I am looking for an automatic way of doing that. For example something like `<a href="http://www.mysite.com/mypage#mjx-eqn-4.1">\eqref{eqn-4.1}</a>`. Then if I have 1000 equations, I will not need to create a new label for all equations (eg. 4.1, 8.12, 6.3, 4.9, etc).

Comment: Perhaps we are having a problem of definitions.  Let's use "tag" to refer to the actual equation number, and "label" to mean a name (never displayed) that refers to the equation number.  Equations can be tagged automatically by MathJax (see the link in my answer).  But the tag for an equation can change if equations are added or deleted before it in the document.  That is why labels are useful, as these give you a fixed name to refer to regardless of the actual tag.  Are you asking for *labels* to be generated automatically?  I do not see how that would work, ...

Comment: ... as any automatic means of supplying them would mean they could change from one viewing of the page to the next.  The label must not change if you edit the document (either the equations before it or the labelled equation itself).  I don't see any way to assign a unique label that doesn't depend on the position or content of the equation.  And how would you know what it was (to refer to it), since labels are never shown?  So I'm still confused by what you are after.  Again, an actual (complete) example of how you think it should work might help.

Comment: Finally, I'm confused by your example: `<a href="http://www.mysite.com/mypage#mjx-eqn-4.1">\eqref{eqn-4.1}</a>`, since this already has an explicit link to `mix-eqn-4.1`, I'm not sure what you want `\eqref{eqn-4.1}` to do.  And if `eqn-4.1` is a label, it is a bad idea to include an equation number (a tag) as part of the label, because that number may change if you edit the `mypage` and add or remove formulas.  If you are going to refer to the actual tag, why use `\eqref` in the first place; why not just `4.1`?  So again, I really don't understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: With latex, when I have a new equation, I define `\label{eq:sum}`. Then I can refer to this equation using `\eqref{eq:sum}`. The tag will be automatically generated. For example, "In equation \eqref{eq:sum}, we can see …" will be translated into "In equation 3.2, we can see …". I never had to define "3.2". With mathjax, this work if the equation is in the same page. My problem is that my equations are not in the same page.

Comment: Suppose on "A.html", I have label{eq:sum}. If I write "In equation \eqref{eq:sum}, we can see …" somewhere in "A.html", then it will be translated into "In equation 3.2, we can see …". That is fine. However, suppose now that I want to write \eqref{eq:sum} in page  "B.html". This will not work. What would be nice to have is something like "In equation \eqref{http://www.mysite/eq:sum}, we can see …" translated into " In equation 3.2, we can see …". The advantage of that approach is that I never need to explicitly write 3.2, 4.5, 8.6, etc. They are automatically generated.

Comment: I had modified my answer above to say more about the possibilities.

Comment: Thank you for the great discussion !